# htacces redirect question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem i can`t seem to solve. I need to redirect (change/make seo friendly) ,using my htacces file, the following url

from:

http://www.domain.com/cat/subcat/?id=text

to:

http://www.domain.com/cat/subcat/text

Could you please help met with this as noting seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` does not match the querystring in the first parameter of a `RewriteRule`.  You will need a `RewriteCond` instead.  Also, when using rewrite rules in `.htaccess` the leading `/` is not present when matching in the `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^cat/subcat/$ /cat/subcat/%1 [L,R=301]
```

The `%1` is the id that was matched in the `RewriteCond`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I started writing it out like this, but thought he meant the other way round on rereading it.  Otherwise I guess he means redirecting, rather than rewriting. (Also, better to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` to get that match.)

Comment: @Orbling, nice catch, what I had was worthless :)

Comment: Looking at what he posted on the other answer, the full contents of the `.htaccess`, the rewrite might be sufficient if it passes through to the final rule which maps all things to `index.php`, providing that process is doing all of the interpretation on the rewritten URL.  Would have to be careful about using the right variable.  The redirect is a better approach generally though, as you have it, as incorrect URLs should be *changed* not *handled*.